# Reading Commented Details in a File Like wordpress theme engine

Tags: wordpress

How does WordPress read commented details from a file?

I tried to trace out by reading out WordPress core file. 
I also tried using  using `file_get_contents` function & file read function in php but I can't get the exact value what I need.

E.g. I have added the below comment in my **css** file and that gets printed in WP-admin how is it possible?

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme 
Author: Team
Author URI: http://indiainternetready.com/
*/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer my self

Actualy wordpress has a **File Header** concept which will read all meta data's from wordpress theme css or php files

**File Header Specification** [Per de-facto implementation, File Headers can be specified as the following:]

1. Header are written in a block in the beginning of a PHP or CSS file.
2. A block might be placed in a files comment, like a PHP or CSS
   comment.
3. The whole header block must be placed inside the first 8 192 bytes
   of the file.
4. Headers follow up to each other, one on it's own line.
5. A header consists of a name and a value.
6. Name and value are separated by the ':' character.
7. The name has a minimum of one, and a maximum of three words.
8. The minimum length of a word is three, the maximum length is 12
   characters.
9. A word consists of the characters a-z and A-Z.
10. Words are separated by a single space (d32/x20)
11. A name starts after the beginning of a line or after a whitespace
     character.
12. A name ends before the ':' character. A value starts after the ':'
     character.
13. Sometimes the ':' character is suffixed by a space. This space is
     considered to not be part of the value.
14. A header-value can contain any characters but not a newline.
15. Header values might become filtered before they are used.
16. Header values can but must not contain HTML code in form of certain
     XHTML Elements or HTML Tags.

**Note**: Because of the nature that there are individual headers, the maximum number of words as well as the minimum and maximum number of characters per word are based on default headers. Because this is a subset and not the superset of all header names, this might vary depending on the implementation and plugins you are using.

The Above information got from http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header

---

I have just extracted the exact code which  will get the file meta data which is used in wordpress

**Step 1 :** List all the meta data you want to get

```
$file_headers = array(
        'Name'        => 'Theme Name',
        'ThemeURI'    => 'Theme URI',
        'Description' => 'Description',
        'Author'      => 'Author',
        'AuthorURI'   => 'Author URI',
        'Version'     => 'Version',
        'Template'    => 'Template',
        'Status'      => 'Status',
        'Tags'        => 'Tags',
        'TextDomain'  => 'Text Domain',
        'DomainPath'  => 'Domain Path'
);
```

**Step 2 :**  Add This function your file

```
/**
 * Retrieve metadata from a file.
 *
 * Searches for metadata in the first 8kiB of a file, such as a plugin or theme.
 * Each piece of metadata must be on its own line. Fields can not span multiple
 * lines, the value will get cut at the end of the first line.
 *
 * If the file data is not within that first 8kiB, then the author should correct
 * their plugin file and move the data headers to the top.
 *
 * @param string $file Path to the file
 * @param array $default_headers List of headers, in the format array('HeaderKey' => 'Header Name')
 */

function get_file_data( $file, $default_headers) {

    $fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );
    $file_data = fread( $fp, 8192 );
    fclose( $fp );
    $file_data = str_replace( "\r", "\n", $file_data );
    $all_headers = $default_headers;

    foreach ( $all_headers as $field => $regex ) {
        if (preg_match( '/^[ \t\/*#@]*' . preg_quote( $regex, '/' ) . ':(.*)$/mi', $file_data, $match ) 
            && $match[1])
            $all_headers[ $field ] = trim(preg_replace("/\s*(?:\*\/|\?>).*/", '', $match[1]));
        else
            $all_headers[ $field ] = '';
    }

    return $all_headers;
}
```

**Step 3 :** Add The Below Comment In File

```
/*
Theme Name: Stack Grace
Theme URI: http://stackoverflow.com
Author: Stack Over Flow
Author URI: http://stackoverflow.com
Description: Sample of Stack Overflow.
Version: 2.1
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: black, brown, orange, tan, white, yellow, light, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, fluid-layout, responsive-layout, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, translation-ready
Text Domain: This theme, like SS, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

**Step 4 :** Call the function like below [
Replace `test.php` with your file]

```
$data = get_file_data( 'test.php', $file_headers);
foreach($data as $key => $val){
    echo $key." --> ".$val."<br/>";
}
```

**Final :** The output will be like below

```
Name --> Stack Grace
ThemeURI --> http://stackoverflow.com
Description --> Sample of Stack Overflow.
Author --> Stack Over Flow
AuthorURI --> http://stackoverflow.com
Version --> 2.1
Template -->
Status -->
Tags --> black, brown, orange, tan, white, yellow, light, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, fluid-layout, responsive-layout, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, translation-ready
TextDomain --> This theme, like SS, is licensed under the GPL.
DomainPath -->
```